# How to observe "drastic difference" in shared and unshared cases when using JMH states?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I take a look at [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) tool.

In sample file [JMHSample_03_States](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/2856725c3a81/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_03_States.java) they says:

```
  ============================== HOW TO RUN THIS TEST: ====================================

  You are expected to see the drastic difference in shared and unshared cases,
  because you either contend for single memory location, or not. This effect
  is more articulated on large machines.

  You can run this test:

  a) Via the command line:
     $ mvn clean install
     $ java -jar target/benchmarks.jar JMHSample_03 -wi 5 -i 5 -t 4 -f 1
     (we requested 5 measurement/warmup iterations, with 4 threads, single fork)
```

My result for java 1.8.20.0 and Intel i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:24

Benchmark                                   Mode  Samples           Score  Score error  Units
o.s.JMHSample_03_States.measureShared      thrpt        5  1547894580.996  3632128.044  ops/s
o.s.JMHSample_03_States.measureUnshared    thrpt        5  1571371998.011  6150584.658  ops/s
```

What is the "drastic difference"? Difference between measureShared (1547894580) and measureUnshared (1571371998) less then 2%

Comment: Well, are you sure you requested 4 threads, as example suggests?

Comment: @Aleksey Shipilev  Yes, of course. Look at https://gist.github.com/qwazer/cbd8d8300394ae913886 here

Comment: Also I notice, than someone has different result https://github.com/artyushov/idea-jmh-plugin/blob/develop/research/results.md May be I need register the bug in bug-tracker?

Comment: This does sound like an environmental issue, does not look like a bug yet. How many CPUs your system has? Gist your /proc/cpuinfo, please?

Comment: 4 core. https://gist.github.com/qwazer/ecf4e07c56b2b5885a80

Comment: Okay, one more thing. Run the benchmarks, and watch for `mpstat -P ALL 1` on the secondary terminal. Do you have all CPUs busy?

Comment: yes: https://gist.github.com/qwazer/05af7a99bb262c712472

Comment: That's weird. This does look like environmental issue, because the difference is perfectly repoducible on other machines I've tried. Can you give me a ssh access to your machine?

Comment: It's not very easy for me, becouse I'm behind very restrictive firefall. But I'll try to make the tunnell  and will mail it to aleksey@shipilev.net in 15-30 minutes

Comment: So did you find out what was the problem? It's very interesting!

Comment: @TagirValeev, no. I give acess to my machine to Aleksey, but we didn't find cause of problem.  Aleksey added volatile to JMHSample_03_States http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/rev/f481bc602a57.

Comment: @aleksey-shipilev @tagir-valeev I found that disabling of the JIT compiler with `-Djava.compiler=NONE` option gives  some difference with non-volatile fields on my platform.  https://gist.github.com/qwazer/e4341f0153f525f088fa227348e69734